# How to get the list of properties retrieved in @Value inside my Spring Application

Tags: java, spring

In my application, I have dozen of properties mapped to my bean attributes like that:

```
@Value("#{props['prop1']}")
private String prop1;

@Value("#{props['prop2']}")
private String prop2;

@Value("#{props['prop3']}")
private String prop3;
```

In my property file, I always need to define the values:

```
prop1=value1
prop2=value2
prop3=specific-value
```

It's heavy because most of the properties are often the same. I would prefer to define default values in my code and then override what I need in my property file. The code can looks like this:

```
@Value("#{props['prop1'] ?: value1}")
private String prop1;

@Value("#{props['prop2'] ?: value2}")
private String prop2;

@Value("#{props['prop3'] ?: value3}")
private String prop3;
```

And in my property file, I just change `prop3`:

```
prop3=specific-value
```

This is handy because we have a smaller property file that is easier to maintain. Spring boot can also help more by picking the right property file according to the enabled profile.

Now I have one concern: as a developer, how I can know all the configuration points inside my application? If we are forced to add all the properties to the property file, then we can have the list of supported properties easily. However with an approach where only a few properties are defined, we lose this benefit and it becomes tricky to know what property can be changed.

I'm curious to know how this issue has been already addressed before and how. I would expect to have a utility tool like a maven plugin that can scan my beans, detects inside them the attributes annotated with `@Value` and prints a table of all properties and their default value defined in the application.

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot? Then it would be possible.

Comment: Yes, how achieve this with boot?

Comment: Well, it depends on how you are able to change your code. If you use configuration classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`, you can use a maven plugin which creates a JSON file with all possible properties (main purpose for the file is IDE completion in properties files). See the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties and here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Yes it's really helps but it requires to completely refactor the code.